# Connect RDS Aurora Postgres SQL from one account to another account using AWS Privatelink(VPC Endpoint) with IAM Authentication in AWS

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora, vpc-endpoint, aws-private-link

I want to connect RDS Aurora Postgres SQL from one account to another account using AWS Privatelink(VPC Endpoint) with IAM Authentication. I have below setup.

Account A:
I have VPC Endpoint service which is pointing to NLB and NLB is redirect request to RDS Aurora Postgres SQL.The VPC Endpoint service has allowed principal for 'Account B'.

Account B:
I have created VPC Endpoint which has pointed to 'Account A' VPC Endpoint service. I have application which is connect my RDS DB using VPC Endpoint dns name as host name in psql command(Instead of RDS Endpoint).

I can able to connect RDS from 'Account B' via VPC Endpoint with above setup using credentials mode(username and password of DB).

But I am unable connect RDS with IAM Authentication. How to connect RDS from different account using VPC Endpoint with IAM Authentication.

Could anyone give me details steps?